# Focusing on text input field after opening activity from push notification

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have NoteListActivity, where I have search bar, that is called via method:

```
private void searchClicked(MenuItem item) {
    searchText.setText(AppConstant.NULL_STRING);
    searchBgr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    searchText.requestFocus();
    showKeyBoard();
}
```

And I need to open that specific method from notification bar.
I managed to open that specific activity, but I have no idea how to call method inside activity that I want to focus on.

This is the intent for notification bar activity:

```
Intent searchIntent = new Intent(context, NoteListActivity.class);
    searchIntent.putExtra(AppConstant.FIXED_NOTIFICATION_SEARCH_KEY, true);
    int searchPendingIntentId = AppConstant.FIXED_NOTIFICATION_SEARCH_ID;
    PendingIntent searchPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, searchPendingIntentId, searchIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onCreate(){

    if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra (AppConstant.FIXED_NOTIFICATION_SEARCH_KEY,false) ){

        searchText.setText(AppConstant.NULL_STRING);
        searchBgr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        searchText.requestFocus();
        showKeyBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error for "cannot resolve method getBoolean, while getBooleanExtra doesn't opens activity from notification bar.

Comment: What do you mean  while getBooleanExtra doesn't opens activity from notification bar?